# Field Permissions on ContentVersionHistory

Tags: lightning-web-components, contentversion

I'm trying to display field history for some custom fields on the ContentVersion object. This object has some interesting properties, one of which is that field security cannot be explicitly set on its fields.  Another is that although field history tracking can be enabled, it cannot be displayed as a related list.

As a workaround, I created a Lightning Web Component that is a datatable that displays the field history for Content Version.  This actually works great EXCEPT that the data does not display to non-admin users.  They can see the component, but not the data.

So, looking for any advice on how I can expose that data to non-Admins.  Or, happy to hear any alternate solutions that result in the field tracking history being visible to end users when looking at a File.

Thanks in advance.

Edit for clarity: What system permission governs access to ContentVersionHistory?

Comment: Did you use Apex here or LWC with standard modules?

Comment: Have you tried to define your LWC controller as 'without sharing'?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava and @metasync I used a very simple Apex class "without sharing" that takes the recordId and returns `List<ContentVersionHistory>`